# React Virtualized Window Scroller not rendering new rows

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I'm trying to follow the [example](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/WindowScroller) for the window scroller in react virualized but can't seem to get any new rows to render ([See example](https://s6.gifyu.com/images/2021-07-05-13-28-34_1.gif)).

Here's the code I wrote:

```
const Row = ({ index, isScrolling, isVisible, key, style }) => {
    console.log(`Rendering row ${index}`);
    return tracks[index] ? (
      <TrackItem
        key={key}
        id={tracks[index].id}
        title={tracks[index].title}
        artist={tracks[index].artist}
        album={tracks[index].album}
        explicit={tracks[index].explicit}
        albumArtKey={tracks[index].albumArtUrl}
        trackKey={tracks[index].trackUrl}
        style={style}
      />
    ) : (
      <></>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="bg-white h-library-full-height">
      <Header trackCount={tracks.length} />
      <WindowScroller ref={windowScrollerRef}>
        {({ height, isScrolling, registerChild, onChildScroll, scrollTop }) => (
          <div className="flex-auto">
            <AutoSizer disableHeight>
              {({ width }) => (
                <div ref={registerChild}>
                  <List
                    className="outline-none"
                    ref={listRef}
                    autoHeight
                    height={height}
                    isScrolling={isScrolling}
                    onScroll={onChildScroll}
                    overscanRowCount={5}
                    rowCount={tracks.length}
                    rowHeight={48}
                    rowRenderer={Row}
                    scrollToIndex={scrollToIndex}
                    scrollTop={scrollTop}
                    width={width}
                  />
                </div>
              )}
            </AutoSizer>
          </div>
        )}
      </WindowScroller>
    </div>
  );
```

For whatever reason the example doesn't seem to work in my app. It does however work when I use an AutoSizer without the WindowScroller attached. Struggling to see the issue here.